# Как нажать на Enter в клавиатуре с помощью JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужен скрипт, который сам нажимает <kbd>Enter</kbd> в `input` (текстовое поле) без помощи пользователя.
Искал ответ в гугле, но нашёл только как отслеживать, а вот как нажать не нашёл.
Может, кто знает, как это сделать? Если нельзя сделать в JQuery, то можно на JS.

Answer (score 1):

Если `input type="button"` или `input type="submit"`, то можно использовать функцию `.click()`

```js
$('input').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="Жми" onclick="alert('Ты на меня нажал..')">
```

Про другие "нажатия", тем более кнопки <kbd>Enter</kbd>, я не слышал

Comment: Я имел ввиду текстовое поле. Очень жаль :(

Comment: ох уж эти начинающие хакеры ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // чета делай
    }
});


const event = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
  view: window,
  keyCode: 13,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});

document.querySelector("form").dispatchEvent(event)
```

Думаю ванильный код тебе тоже зайдет

Comment: Так я говорил, что мне не отследить нужно, а именно нажать.

Comment: поправил, тестируй

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event  дока

Comment: работает, но window.onkeydown это не ловит (я менял keypress на keydown).

Comment: Так ты определись, тебе ловить или нажимать. В примере и нажимает и ловит (выше)

Comment: Так скрипт на сайт должен же понимать, что произошло нажатие на Enter с помощью window.onkeydown